# What is default username and password for IIS server?

Tags: iis

I have configure IIS on my laptop and after that i have started the default site and if i want to open localhost on my browser it ask me for username and password but i had no provide any username and password at the configure time so what is default username and password for localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS doesn't store usernames or passwords. The username or password you're seeing is probably a Windows Authentication prompt - enter your windows login.

If you use a browser like Internet Explorer, it may log in automatically for you (popular in intranet environments).

Answer (score 2):

your iis website should be configured to use windows authentication. and if its asking for username and password, means that your current logged in user has not **sufficient privileges** to access that website.

trying your pc administrator account may solve this problem. also you can find windows authentication in web.config or machine.config file.

Comment: Where in the machine.config file are the usernames and passwords?  Also would those allow me to remotely connect to the computer to edit files?

Comment: Lime - Usernames and passwords are not stored there. The authentication is Windows-based, so you need to be using valid Windows credentials with sufficient rights.